# How to pass value from one test block to other test block in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am learning Playwright and trying to pass value of data from one test block to other test block in test runner. Code as follows:

```
let text = "some text";
let arr = [];
let num;
function data(name) {
  text = name;
  arr.push(text);
  console.log(text);
  num=text;
}
test.describe("test", async () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://google.com/");
    console.log("beforeall");
  });

 // test.beforeEach(async () => {
 //   console.log("before each");
//  });

  test("Navigate to Google", async () => {
    
    data("ANNA");
   
    const url = await page.url();
    expect(url).not.toContain("google");
  });

  test("Search for Playwright", async () => {
    console.log(arr);
    await page.type('input[name="q"]', "Playwright");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    console.log(num);
  });
});
```

If first test block "Navigate to block" is passing then I am getting correct value of "num" which is "Anna" in Second test block.
But if First test block is failing then same "num" is showing "undefined" in second test Block. I tried same for "arr". (I know I did some repeatable coding its just for experimentation purpose)

Output:(fail)

```
[Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:96:3 › test › Navigate to Google
beforeall
ANNA                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 'ANNA' ]                                                                                                                                                           
  1) [Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:96:3 › test › Navigate to Google ===================

    Error: expect(received).not.toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: not "google"
    Received string:        "https://www.google.com/"

       98 |
       99 |     const url = await page.url();
    > 100 |     expect(url).not.toContain("google");
          |                     ^
      101 |   });
      102 |
      103 |   test("Search for Playwright", async () => {

        at C:\Users\piyus\Desktop\Playwright_framework\tests\Demo_testscript.spec.js:100:21

    attachment #1: trace (application/zip) ---------------------------------------------------------
    test-results\Demo_testscript-test-Navigate-to-Google-Microsoft-Edge\trace.zip
    Usage:

        npx playwright show-trace test-results\Demo_testscript-test-Navigate-to-Google-Microsoft-Edge\trace.zip

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    attachment #2: screenshot (image/png) ----------------------------------------------------------
    test-results\Demo_testscript-test-Navigate-to-Google-Microsoft-Edge\test-failed-1.png
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:103:3 › test › Search for Playwright
beforeall
[]                                                                                                                                                                   
some text
undefined                                                                                                                                                            

  1 failed
    [Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:96:3 › test › Navigate to Google ====================
  1 passed (10s)
```

OutPut :(pass : by removing not from first test block)

````
Running 2 tests using 1 worker
[Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:96:3 › test › Navigate to Google
beforeall
ANNA                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 'ANNA' ]                                                                                                                                                           
[Microsoft Edge] › Demo_testscript.spec.js:103:3 › test › Search for Playwright
[ 'ANNA' ]
ANNA
ANNA                                                                                                                                                                 

  2 passed (6s)```
````

Comment: Using globals and shared state between blocks is poor practice and leads to brittle  tests. I suggest making test blocks idempotent to the extent possible.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes you are right but if there is a situation in which I am dependent on previous test block. Is there any way to achieve dependency. If not then I have to create common function and call it again and again in other test blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use serial mode to run your test blocks in the order you need. Then you can also ensure that the variables in your test block get a value.
Check the Playwright docs for how to set it up.

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-retries#serial-mode